# Points of differentiability in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

For the complex function$$f(z)=\cos(|z|^2)$$
Is $f$ differentiable only at $z=0$, or nowhere differentiable?

And if it's differentiable at zero does the derivative $f'(z)$ exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $f(z)=\cos(|z|^2)=\cos(z\overline{z})$. The function is everywhere differentiable, i.e. the [Wirtinger derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives) $\partial_z,\partial_{\overline{z}}$, as well as the usual partial derivatives $\partial_x,\partial_y$ with respect to real and imaginary parts exist at all points $z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}$.

I assume your question is about where it is *complex differentiable*. By the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations), $f$ is complex differentiable at $z$ if and only if
$$\partial_{\overline{z}} f(z)=0$$

Calculate

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{z}} f(z) = -z\sin(z\overline{z})$$

This is zero if and only if $|z|=\sqrt{n\pi}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

At all of these points, $f$ is [complex differentiable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function). Note however that it is not holomorphic anywhere.

Comment: is that for $|z|=\sqrt{n\pi}$ there is $f'(z)=0$ by $f(z)$ is constant for these values..?

Comment: No, $\sin(z\overline{z})=0$ iff $z\overline{z}=|z|^2$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$, so iff $|z|$ is the square root of an integer multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: But, isn't that for $|z|=\sqrt{n\pi}$ there is $f(z)=(-1)^{n}$ follows $f'(z)=0$..?

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that.

Comment: So... Does $f'(z)$ exist ..or what is it..

Comment: $\partial_z f$ exists everywhere and it equals $-\overline{z}\sin(z\overline{z})$. One calls it $f^\prime$ only if additionally $\partial_{\overline{z}} f(z)=0$ (i.e. $f$ is complex-differentiable at $z$) and that is the case only for $|z|=\sqrt{n\pi}$.

Answer (score 0):

To say simply we know that $\mod {a+ib} = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ so if we tend to zero along any curve in the argand plane $\mod z$ also tends to zero and so the function tends to 1.

Comment: How does this answer the question? (If I interpret you correctly, this shows that $f$ is *continuous*.) Also, please write $|z|$ instead of $\mod z$.

Comment: Yes you are right it only says that it is continuous.